# Output error in the simple consult program

Tags: java

I was doing some simple input/output program that as input have name,age and sports that they practice. Finally I have to compute average but i don't know what happened when the while loop is over because the program can't output the average.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CapturarPersonas01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strNombreApellido = "";
        int intEdad = 0;
        String strDeportes = "";
        String espacios = "                                                                              ";
        int intEdadTotal = 0, i = 0;
        StringTokenizer separador = new StringTokenizer(strNombreApellido, " ");

        //ALINIAMIENTO DE LOS HEADERS
        System.out.println("NOMBRE" + espacios.substring(0, 9) + "|" + "APELLIDO" +
            espacios.substring(0, 7) + "|" + "EDAD" + espacios.substring(0, 5) + "|" + "DEPORTES" +
            espacios.substring(0, 9) + "|");
        while (!strNombreApellido.toUpperCase().equals("FIN")) {
            strNombreApellido = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre y apellido");

            //TOKENIZER EL NOMBRE Y APELLIDO
            separador = new StringTokenizer(strNombreApellido, " ");
            String strNombre = separador.nextToken();
            String strApellido = separador.nextToken();

            intEdad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa su edad porfavor"));
            strDeportes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa los deportes");

            //SALIDA
            System.out.print(strNombre + espacios.substring(0, 15 - strNombre.length()) + "|"
                + strApellido + espacios.substring(0, 15 - strApellido.length()) + "|" + intEdad
                + espacios.substring(0, 9 - String.valueOf(intEdad).length()) + "|"
                + strDeportes.substring(0, strDeportes.indexOf(";")));

            strDeportes = strDeportes.substring(strDeportes.indexOf(";"), strDeportes.length());

            //TOKENIZER LOS DEPORTES EXTRA
            separador = new StringTokenizer(strDeportes, ";");
            while (separador.hasMoreTokens()) {
                System.out.print("\n" + espacios.substring(0, 41) + "|" + separador.nextToken());
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            intEdadTotal += intEdad;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("EDAD PROMEDIA: " + (intEdadTotal / i));
    }
}
```

Comment: *"cuz the program cant output the average"* No? That's sad. And what does it instead? Error? Exception? Different Output? Nothing?

Comment: after i input FIN to finish the loop its finish with some error and recomend the debug.

Comment: If you have an error, then why don't you tell us about that?

Comment: i got this [screenshot](http://i61.tinypic.com/mcyecm.png)

Comment: This is not "some error". It just tells you that you're in "debug mode" and your code hit a break point, so it likes to switch the eclipse UI into the "debug view" with different controls.

Comment: This is a help page about debugging in eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/debugging-with-eclipse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is coming from taking the input after entering your while loop.

```
    strNombreApellido = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre y apellido");
    while (!strNombreApellido.toUpperCase().equals("FIN")) {
    //stuff

    //take name again at the end of the loop iteration
    strNombreApellido = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre y apellido");
}
```

you must take the input first or you will always enter your loop where you try to get your name and apellido and that is where your exception is occuring. If you only change this and run the program you will get a divide by 0 error on this line

```
System.out.println("EDAD PROMEDIA: " + (intEdadTotal / i));
```

i started the value of i as 1 and that removes the error if no names are entered.

Comment: I like your answer Ryan you need to learn quiet a few languages

Comment: hm i mean all works well untill i finish the loop while with "FIN", but the logic of this line is just to place perfect the input dates using blanc spaces

Comment: Well, since you already started, there is no point in creating another answer: Your answer might be true, but OPs problem (he talked about) is something different. He get's an exception when he tries to finish the loop using *"FIN"* as input for *"Ingrese el nombre y apellido"*. The problem about that isn't hard to spot ;P, so wanna expand your answer?

Comment: i'll take a quick peak

Comment: Btw: You can test the program "safely" (without getting the mentioned OutOfBoundsException) by using a space for the first input (e.g. `"A B"`), a number for the second and a semicolon for the third `"A;B"`. Then it asks for the first input again. Good luck :). (btw: the missing semicolon was the cause for your expection ;)).

Comment: 1st input is for the (name thurname) with space
2nd input is for age
3rd input is for sports (separating with ; each one) i just wanted to do the program without exeption for "perfect" input and after this edit the program with exeptions :)

Comment: it works fine for me without any problems ,what problems it introduces ?

Comment: me not knowing Spanish i assumed we were entering different people, their age and something about sports. Then each iteration you entered a different person and his details. The exit of the loop comes from a sentinel value, the name, which you enter for each iteration. The math for Eda promeda might be wrong as i don't know what that is, but thats all i can see,

Comment: If you enter FIN as your name for any iteration of the loop it will exit.

Comment: Yeah we entering different people and the first input is out of the loop so there is no problem of inputing first name twice look at the [result](http://i58.tinypic.com/28wh66f.jpg) it works fine

Comment: Oh right, you moved the input for the name to the end of the loop, missed that, stupid me. The program flow is a bit worse there, but that doesn't matter much now. I deleted my comments about that "problem", because they were nonsense.